# Getting values from indicator variables in R

Tags: r, statistics

Firstly I had to model the coordinates of two points in a 20m X 30m rectangle. Obviously these points follow a uniform distribution so this is the first part of my code:

```
    X1 <- runif(1,0,20)
    X2 <- runif(1,0,30)
    point1 <- c(X1,X2)
    point1
```

I used the same code for the second point ('point2') but replaced the X1 and X2 with Y1 and Y2 respectively.

I then had to find the distance between the two points:

```
    distance <- sqrt(((X1-Y1)^2)+((X2-Y2)^2))
```

Now if I define A as the event where the points are within 5m to 10m of each other, I need to find the indicator variable of this event.
This is what I got to, but I'm not sure if it's right:

```
    x=0
    if (distance < 10 & distance > 5)
    {
     x=1
    }
    Z <- c(distance,x)
```

If I were to repeat these commands 1000 times, how would I store the values in each simulation and find the min and max separation values in the 1000 reps?

Comment: To address the last sentence.You would create 2 1000 x 2 matrices. As I said in my answer, learn to work with matrices.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by indicator variable and the min and max separations. If by indicator variable you mean the 0/1 of whether a point is within the distance, then @SimonO101 has shown you something that will work and I simplified it in my comment there. For the min/max separation, do you mean the find the min and max distances for those events that have indicator variable == 1? If so, use `min(distance[distance >= 5 & distance <= 10])` (or `max()`) to get the minimum `distance` for the the selected events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At one point you use X1 and X2 and later refer to Y1 which has not been defined. I'm pretty sure you  want to use:

```
 points <- cbind(X1, X2)
```

Context suggests that you wanted to keep the X1 and X2 values in a "parallel" arrangement and defining a matrix rather than a non-dimensioned object will accomplish that.

Last question answered using R's matrix operations:

```
points1 <- matrix( runif(2000), ncol=2)
points1 <- matrix( runif(2000), ncol=2)
dists <- rowSums( (points1-points2)^2 )
Z <- dists <10 & dists >5
```

Comment: He defines Y1 in the body text as to what he is doing.

Comment: @SimonO101 *she but I suppose that's irrelevant

Comment: @Mathlete So sorry! I read Mat as Matt or Matthew. I must remember to make less assumptions. Sorry.

Comment: My "point" as it were still holds. Using `c` creates confusion. Using cbind leads to clarity as well as the option of using vectorized funtions for this process.

Comment: @Mathlete `?cbind` will enlighten you - learn to use R's help tools. It is column bind.

Comment: There isn't really a need to `cbind` them as far as the distance function goes. You could just call them as vectors.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I'm familiar with R's help tools thank you, they just don't happen to explain certain things very well.

Comment: What is the benefit of cbind in this context?

Comment: @Mathlete You are doing this point by point in your Q. If you generate all 1000 coordinates in one go then you have vectors of length 1000 for `x1`, `x2` etc. You don't want to concatenate them with `c()` as for example `c(x1, x2)` would give a vector of length 2000, when what you really want is a matrix with 1000 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: Look at the code I added. It should be clear that using matrices adds to the clarity and ease of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Close. Use `ifelse` or simply a vectorised form to define your event. For 1000 samples all you need to do is use `runif` to generate 1000 samples. Also there is no need to `c(X1 , X2)`, you can just call them as vectors in your distance calculation...

```
#Just make 1000 calls to runif 
X1 <- runif(1000,0,20)
X2 <- runif(1000,0,30)
Y1 <- runif(1000,0,20)
Y2 <- runif(1000,0,30)
distance <- sqrt(((X1-Y1)^2)+((X2-Y2)^2))

head(distance)
#[1]  9.050522 19.512849 10.413407  7.736564  2.742174 13.729397

# gives 1 if points are within 5 to 10m of each other
event <- ifelse ( distance >= 5 & distance <= 10 , 1 , 0 )

#Or even better, from @GavinSimpson's comment just use a vectorised form (we use as.nuemric to turn TRUE / FALSE into 1 and 0, but you could leave that out if you wish)
event <- as.numeric( distance >= 5 & distance <= 10 )

head( event )
#[1] 1 0 0 1 0 0

# And the minimum and maximum sepration distance of those events
min(distance[distance >= 5 & distance <= 10])
#[1] 5.017296
max(distance[distance >= 5 & distance <= 10])
#[1] 9.989868
```

Comment: `ifelse` is *not* vectorised in the sense that is commonly meant. It just hides a loop. For this you just need a logical vector `distance >= 5 & distance <= 10` as R will treat that as `1` for `TRUE` and `0` for `FALSE`. If you want you can wrap it in `as.numeric()`, but you certainly *don't* need `ifelse` here.

Comment: But how would you find the min and max separations?

Comment: Also note that you are *not* making 1000 calls to `runif()` there, but only a single call generating 1000 random deviates.

Comment: @Mathlete I don't understand. The code looks at each element of distance in turn and if it is greater than or equal to 5 AND less than or equal to 10 it will return 1, else it will return 0. Does that make sense. You can use a vectorised form which  will be even faster (not that for 1000 calls it will make any noticeable difference)

Comment: @SimonO101 sorry I meant, how would I find the minimum distance and maximum distance of separation between the two points?

Comment: @GavinSimpson Again , I edited the explanation to point out that 1000 calls are not made to runif. Thank you for pointing out sloppy errors. It's good to be precise.

Comment: @Mathlete I am not sure I understand, but I think you are simply looking for `min( distance)` and `max(distance)` to find the min and max separation of the 1000 values. But if you want the min and max seperation of all the points between 5 and 10m @GavinSimpson has given you the answer in the comments under your question.

Comment: Or maybe `min(distance[event])` and `max(distance[event])`?