# Convert numeric vector to binary (0/1) based on limit

Tags: r, vector

I have a numeric vector:

```
p = c(0.69, 0.43, 0.72, 0.62, 0.29, 0.7)
```

I wish to compare the values to a limit, e.g. 0.5. If the values are equal or larger than the cut-off, the result should 1. Values less than 0.5 should become 0.

I tried `ifelse`, but it errors:

```
newvector = rep(0, length(p))
newvector = ifelse(p >= 0.5, newvector = 1, newvector = 0)
# Error in ifelse(p >= 0.5, newvector = 1, newvector = 0) : 
#   unused arguments (newvector = 1, newvector = 0)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to make `newvector` beforehand and using it as an argument to `ifelse` is causing the error.

Try this...

```
newvector <- ifelse( p>=0.5 , 1 , 0 )
```

But even better just do it vectorised...

```
newvector <- as.integer( p >= 0.5 )
```

Comment: +1 for the second method.  Generally avoid "if..." when direct vector operations will suffice.

Comment: @Roland You should discuss this with Gavin Simpson. See the comments under [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15526978/1478381) where I refer to `ifelse` being vectorised and being corrected on this. `ifelse` just hides the loop apparently (I assume in the way that the `apply` family do, in C code)

Comment: @GavinSimpson perhaps you can wade in on why `ifelse` is not vectorised (see comments above this one). (will SO notify him if I include his handle in a comment?!)

Comment: Just profile it to figure out if its vectorized; should be real easy to tell one way or the other.

Comment: @ClaytonStanley As I`ve written above, `ifelse` uses conditional subsetting. If you consider that vectorized (although it is a vector scan), than `ifelse` is vectorized. Of course at its heart (the C code) it's still a loop. An alternative would be the binary search offered by data.table (which requires setting a key).

Comment: If the downvoter would explain the downvote, that would be useful for me from a learning perspective. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just use :

```
newvector <- ifelse(p>=0.5,1,0)
```

The second and third arguments of `ifelse` are not expressions but the values to be returned.

Comment: dang it how could I have missed this? Thx for the answer, I feel incredibly stupid now

Comment: Never underestimate the power of R to make you feel stupid :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `findInterval` for this particular case:

```
findInterval(p, .5)
```

Answer (score 2):

in this case you could use `newvector<-round(p)` instead of the `ifelse`.

Comment: Only so long as you know `p < 1.5` is always true -- and that `p > -0.5` is true as well.  So be cautious in the general case :-)